# How to perform triggers one hour in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, time, triggers, intervals

I created triggers, hoping it can work in a while, such as one hour.How can I execute this problem?

Comment: Generally triggers need an event to trigger them. Event like INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE ... Is this what you are looking for or you need a stored procedure to be run at some time interval, say every hour?

Answer (score 3):

Triggers in databases aren't generally meant to happen at certain *times,* they're meant to happen in conjunction with certain *events.*

For example, the PostgreSQL documentation for [create trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html) shows the events as:

- `INSERT`;
- `UPDATE [ OF column_name [, ... ] ]`;
- `DELETE`; and
- `TRUNCATE`.

If you want something to happen hourly (for example), you would use a tool such as `cron`, a job scheduler under many different UNIX-like operating systems, or Windows Scheduled Tasks.